# Rack/Sinatra Method Not Allowed

Tags: ruby, sinatra, rack

I am developing a simple web app using Sinatra and using `rack` as the middleware and hence have a `config.ru`.
To run the application I use `shotgun config.ru`.

I have no problem when the application does a `GET` request. But my app has a couple of `POST` requests, and when I submit a form via `POST` method, I get this strange error:

```
Method Not Allowed
```

Following is the content of my `config.ru`:

```
require "rack"
require 'rack/contrib/try_static'
require File.expand_path("app", File.dirname(__FILE__))

use Rack::TryStatic, :root => File.join(App::SETTINGS.source, App::SETTINGS.site.config['destination']), :urls => %w[/]

run App
```

Any idea what could resolve the issue?

Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue.
It was a problem with `rack`.

I replaced

```
use Rack::TryStatic, 
    :root => File.join(App::SETTINGS.source, App::SETTINGS.site.config['destination']), 
    :urls => %w[/]
```

with:

```
use Rack::Static,
    :urls => ["/#{App::SETTINGS.site.config['destination']}"],
    :root => File.join(App::SETTINGS.source, App::SETTINGS.site.config['destination'])
```

Comment: The options you've given are different, and [TryStatic calls Static under the hood anyway](https://github.com/rack/rack-contrib/blob/1.1.0/lib/rack/contrib/try_static.rb#L21).

Comment: That's true. But TryStatic will give you a 405 error for any requests other than a `GET`.

Comment: Because static pages are only supposed to be called with a GET. They're static and require no processing. You've used `:urls` with `%w[/]` instead of `:try` which means the middleware will intercept *all* requests, so and POST et al routes that you've defined will not be reached.

Comment: I have changed the urls option. Did you check the answer?

Answer (score 0):

The following will not respond to posts:

```
get '/hi' do
 "Hello World!"
end
```

It is quite possible that you will need to do something like this:

```
post '/hi' do
  # do post stuff
end
```

Comment: Yup I know that! I have defined using `post` and not `get`. Still no luck :(